# The 2nd derivative of $x^2+y^2=4$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Finding the first derivative of the function $x^2+y^2=4$ gives you
$$y'=-\frac{x}{y} $$
Then to find the 2nd derivative you apply the quotient rule, which looks like this
$$y''=\frac{y(-1)-(-x)y'}{y^2}$$
which gives you 
$$\frac{-y+xy'}{y^2} $$
But after looking in the back of the book I realized my answer was wrong.

Comment: Did you plug back in $y' = -x/y$ in your expression for $y''$?

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: @D.B. I did not, thanks for the hint

Comment: and don't forget to simplify it using $x^2+y^2=4$ afterwards.

Comment: @user10354138 Yep I figured it out now

Comment: Note that when implicit differentiation is needed, there can often be many different equivalent forms of the answer. It is usually desirable, however, not to have other derivatives in your final answers (only the original variables). So you don't want to leave $y'$ in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$y'=-\frac{x}{y}$$ we get
$$y''=-\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}=-\frac{y}{y^2}+\frac{x}{y^2}y'$$ and this is equal to
$$y''=-\frac{y}{x^2}+\frac{x}{y^2}\cdot \left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)$$ which can simplified to
$$y''=-\frac{1}{y}-\frac{x^2}{y^3}$$

Comment: You seem to have changed a $y^2$ into a $x^2$ going from line two to three.

Comment: Yes, you have right, corrected! Note: Errare humanum est!

Answer (score 4):

Differentiating $x^2+y^2=4$ twice with respect to $x$ gives
$$
2+2(y')^2+2yy''=0
$$
so
$$
yy''=-1-(y')^2=-1-\frac{x^2}{y^2}=-\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^2}=-\frac4{y^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
y''=-\frac4{y^3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\color{blue}{x  =2\cos\theta}$ and $\color{blue}{y= 2\sin\theta}$ which satisfies the given equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}  =\frac{{dy}/{d\theta}}{{dx}/{d\theta}} = -\cot\theta $$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d( -\cot\theta )}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx} =- \csc^2\theta\frac{1}{2\sin\theta} = \frac{-1}{2\sin^3\theta} = -\frac{4}{y^3}$$